# Treetop seems to fail on a simple grammar (5 rules)

Tags: ruby, treetop

I am trying to write a parser for a subset of C.

The behavior of treetop is difficult to analyze on this simple (further simplified) grammar.

```
 grammar Shyc

 rule functionDef
    type space identifier '('  ')' bloc
 end

 rule type
    'int'
 end

 rule bloc
    '{'  '}' 
 end

 rule identifier
    [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z_]*
 end

 rule space
   [\s]+
 end

end
```

My test case is "int main(){}"

And the error message from treetop is :

```
error at line 1, column 9
failure reason : Expected [a-zA-Z_] at line 1, column 9 (byte 9) after 
compiler.rb:25:in `parse': Parse error (RuntimeError)
from compiler.rb:73:in `<main>'enter
```

The problem is thus around identifier rule...

The version of treetop : 1.5.3 and Ruby 2.1.1

Any idea ?

Comment: This works for me (tt 1.4.10, ruby 2.0.0p353). Maybe you have a leftover tt-compiled .rb file that's preventing you from loading the up-to-date .treetop file? That has bitten me before.

Comment: Works for me as well, probably a problem with the way your files are set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my test case was in a separate file, with a supplemental end-of-line \n at the end, and that the grammar tested here does not specify how to consume that.

Here is the code that solve the problem. As discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/treetop-dev/gP6ZW16cZkw) on the mailing list of Treetop, the error is weird and somehow misleading but it is difficult in general to automate the emission of a clear message.

```
grammar Shyc

rule functionDef
   type space identifier '('  ')' bloc space?
end

rule type
  'int'
end

rule bloc
  '{'  '}' 
end

rule identifier
   [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z_]*
end

rule space
  [\s\n]+
end
```

end